# Rewriting URL causing opening folder with same name

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I have the following rule to remove `.aspx` from the end of url:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect to clean URL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="RewriteASPX" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Now the problem is that a few specific pages with the same name of folder available in that path, gets opened every time instead of that site.

**This is my site**

[image]

Suppose when i click a link `City.aspx`, it opens the folder(in FTP) with the name **City** instead of opening that page.

**[Edited]**

Removing `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />` solved the problem but now entering the sitename in the url is not working.

Comment: and no, i don't want to change my page or folder name.

Comment: Why don't you [Asp.Net Friedly URLs](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/friendly-urls) to achieve this?

Comment: Why can't i use this method?

Comment: I'm not saying you can't.. What I'm suggesting is friendly url is designed for what you're trying to achieve so why not make use of :/

Comment: @Izzy : See my edited question. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by removing this:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
```

and adding this:

```
<rule name="Canonical" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([a-z]+[.]com)$"/>
      </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}/Index.aspx" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```